# How to have a new form (new event) if I have an arraylist labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to have a new Form if My linklabels is in arraylist?
Because the solution is already existed but in 2005.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
while (i<list.Count)
{
     //creates a new linklabel
    labels[i] = new LinkLabel(); 


    labels[i].Text = list[i]+"";

    labels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    //    this.labels[i].Click += dynamic_LinkClicked;
    y += 30;


   this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);

   i++;

}
```

Comment: Is it web form or Windows form? What issue you are facing with this code

Comment: Windows Form, I am having issue with the  this.labels[i].Click += dynamic_LinkClicked; because Arraylists cannot be associated with the .Click function of the LinkLabel

Answer (score 0):

You should use Array of LinkLabel instead of ArrayList.

But if you have to use ArrayList then you should attach event handler to the linklabel object before you add it to the ArrayList.

You observe that in following code snippet.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
while (i<list.Count)
{
     //creates a new linklabel 
    LinkLabel label = new LinkLabel();
    label.Text = list[i]+"";

    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    label.Click += dynamic_LinkClicked;
    y += 30;

   labels[i] = label;
   this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
   i++;
}
   public void dynamic_LinkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, string [] a)
   {
        Courseviewinside inside = new Courseviewinside();
        inside.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Comment: Im sorry that I didnt put the labels arraylist. LinkLabel[] labels = new LinkLabel[list.Count]; in the posts , I dont know how to attach the link label object because it is dynamic.

Comment: What problem you are facing with the solution I suggested? What do you mean by dynamic? Are you facing any error? What is `dynamic_LinkClicked`? Can you share it's code too?

Comment: public void dynamic_LinkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, string [] a)
       {
            Courseviewinside inside = new Courseviewinside();
            inside.ShowDialog();


        }

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer... does this approach work for you?

Comment: nope it didn't work. I think its because of my array linklabels granting them to have a "Click event button" which will go to a new form. I  need help :(

Comment: Ok.. I got the picture... The reason you are not able to attach the event is because the event handler signature is not proper. Event handler for Click event expects only two parameters `object sender` and `EventArgs e`. You have extra parameter `string[] a` in `dynamic_LinkClicked`. You need to remove that. If you can explain why you need that parameter in the click event may be I can suggest some other solution for that.